# Inability to check MS Word 2003 document into SharePoint 2010 Library

Tags: 2010, check-in

Several users have recently been experiencing an issue when trying to check-in a document into a SharePoint Library. Microsoft Windows Explorer notifies them that "This document was checked out to your local drafts folder but the local copy could not be found or is on a different computer. Upload the local changes or discard your check out to continue editing."
We use MS SharePoint 2010; my team uses MS Office 2007 for document creation; our current practice is to save all documents to 2003 (.doc, .xls, .ppt) as many of our wider colleague base still operates MS Office 2003.
How can this issue be resolved to allow us to successfully check-in documents into our SharePoint Library without losing changes?
Thanks.

N.B. This issue has occured for a handful of users. Most have had no problem checking in the same document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a copy open you can Save it to say your desktop and then upload it to the library.  As long as you don't change the name of the existing document it will add it as a new version and you wont lose your changes.

The local drafts folder is stored with user's profile folders on their local machines.  It sounds like something has probably altered this and made it out of sync with the open document, it was physically removed, or there is a permission issue. You would need to run something like process monitor to track down what is happening on the client site. sometimes Anti-virus can be the culprit.

For these affected users - I would recommend they also try and run an office repair, restart their computers and then try again.

Answer (score 0):

If this has only happened to a handful of users with 2003, and other 2003 users are okay, check their local group policy.  You may need to kick the impacted users policies pretty firmly.  Specifically you want to look and make sure that the Web Client service is running on their local laptop for WebDAV connections.